# Using javascript:function syntax versus jQuery selector to make Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do front-end dev only like 10% of the time and am curious which is the better way to handle making ajax calls. These calls are just posting data to a web app that specifies an action name and an id.

```
<a href='javascript:addToList({'action':'set-default-time-zone','id':23})'>set default timezone</a>
<div class='add-to-list action-set-default-time-zone id-23'>set default timezone</div>
```

I have used both over the years but am not sure which one is preferred. It seems like they get to the same point in the end. Would you consider these to be the two best alternatives and is one better than the other?

I've implemented the div method as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-to-list').click(function(){
        var id=getId($(this).attr("class"));
        var action=getAction($(this).attr("class"));
        $.post('/api/' + action,function(data){
          ...
        },'json')
    });
});


function getAction(str){
    var parts=str.split(' ');
    var phrase='action-';
    for(i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
        var val=parts[i].match(phrase);
        if(val!=null){
            var action=parts[i].split('action-');
            return action[1];
        }
    }
}

function getId(piece){
    var parts=piece.split('id-');
    var frag_id=parts[parts.length-1];
    var part_id=frag_id.split('-');
    var id=part_id[part_id.length-1];
    return id;
}
```

The link method would seem straightforward.

thx

Comment: I much prefer taking the behavior out of markup so that cleans up and clarifies both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the second approach is what you would call [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). It is believed to be a more robust approach (I'll avoid the term *better* here.)

However, your implementation is a bit over-complicated. It could be tuned down to:

HTML:

```
<div class="add-to-list" data-action="set-default-time-zone" data-id="23">
    set default timezone
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add-to-list').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var action = $(this).attr("data-action");

        $.post('/api/' + action, function(data) {
          // ...
        }, 'json')
    });
});
```

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) allows for attributes starting with `data-` to be carrying user-defined data. And it's also backward compatible (will work with older browsers.)

Comment: I was just about to respond something similar to this.  The primary advantage of using `data-action` (or whatever) is that in the future, when some other developer re-factors the CSS, the classes can be completely changed because the javascript isn't dependent on them.  This helps break less JS in the long run.

Comment: thanks. so in the data-* examples, would these would come out as non-validating in HTML4 browsers? Would that be only significant drawback? Just curious as this is for client and wouldn't want that to come up. thanks again.

Comment: Well, according to http://validator.w3.org/, these attributes raise validation errors for HTML 4.01 and XHTML doctypes. But it should *work* anyway, even if they raise validation errors according to the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
<a href='javascript:addToList({'action':'set-default-time-zone','id':23})'>set default timezone</a>
```

Method 2:

```
<div class='add-to-list action-set-default-time-zone id-23'>set default timezone</div>
```

Method 2 is preferred because you would be practicing unobtrusive style of coding with a much clearer separation of your markup and your scripting code. It is alot easier to read and debug, and there for more maintainable. Also, i would propose instead of using CSS classes to pass data, to use the jQuery.data() method to store data on elements.

Comment: cool - looking into jQuery.data() now but kinda early in the morning - 7AM