# how to select data-id and data-action in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is a follow-up to this question: [Using javascript:function syntax versus jQuery selector to make Ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271149/using-javascriptfunction-syntax-versus-jquery-selector-to-make-ajax-calls)

How would I select this fragment?

```
<div data-id="54" data-action="follow-global-id" class="add-to-list">here is my answer</div>
```

I have the id value below and tried this

```
 $('.add-to-list[data-action|="action-follow-global-id"][data-id|=id]').text('here is the things jtjt in the id value');
```

but no dice. Need to be AND'ing these together.

thx for help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Didn't test it, but should work:

```
var id = 54;
$('.add-to-list[data-action=follow-global-id][data-id='+id+']').text('something');
```

Comment: Although it might work without them, please note that quotes around the attribute values are *mandatory*.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
$('.add-to-list[data-action="follow-global-id"][data-id="54"]').
    text('here is the things jtjt in the id value');
```

Here's a full code example you can execute to test:

```
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.add-to-list[data-action="follow-global-id"][data-id="54"]').
            text('here is the things jtjt in the id value');
    });
    </script>
    <div data-id="54" data-action="follow-global-id" class="add-to-list">here is my answer</div> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('.add-to-list[data-action|="follow-global-id"][data-id]').each(function (i) {
    $(this).text('here is the things ' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ' in the id value');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

all you need to do is

```
$("[data-action=value")
```

OR

```
$("[data-id=value"])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.