# Jquery use data-id and disable and clear input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a variety of reasons I want to change the code below to look out for data attributes rather than a class called "mygroup".

HTML

```
<select id="apply">
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="website">Website</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="input" id="email" placeholder="test@test.com" data-id="application"/>
<input type="text" class="input" id="website" placeholder="www.example.com" data-id="application"/>
<textarea class="input" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="text*" data-id="applicationdetails"></textarea>
```

JS

```
// Apply Fields
function applyField() {
    $(document).on('change', '#apply',function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
            elem = $("#"+selected);
        $(".mygroup").addClass('hidden');
        elem.removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $("#apply").trigger('change');
};
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xDA9p/)

How do I change the code above apply to data-id of "application" rather than using the class "mygroup". For bonus points can anyone tell me how to clear the content of the field that is being hidden and also disable it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to select data-id and data-action in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278854/how-to-select-data-id-and-data-action-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply refer to it as `$('[data-id="application"]')`.

As for the clearing and disabling, use `.prop()` and `.val('')`:

```
$('[data-id="application"]').addClass('hidden').prop('disabled', true).val('');
elem.removeClass('hidden').prop('disabled', false);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xDA9p/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the attribute selector, ie all elements with attribute `data-id` instead of having class `myClass`

```
function applyField() {
    $(document).on('change', '#apply',function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
            elem = $("#"+selected);
        $("input[data-id]").addClass('hidden');
        elem.removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $("#apply").trigger('change');
};

jQuery(function($){
    applyField();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KkqN3/)